Query generated by Entity Framework Core is too slow
We're currently working with .NET 8 and EF Core 8.
We're having time issues with a query we use to count the results to paginate them after. We started with a query that took 40 seconds to execute and we were able to reduce the time for 40 seconds to 4 increasing the e-DTUs from 5 to 50 per database in Azure SQL Elastic Pool
We have an events system in place with an Action table, Event table (this tables is used to store events for all modules) and Claim (table we query). Action has 20 rows, Event has 640.338 and Claim has 62.000.
This is how the tables look like.

Relationship between Claim and Event is soft because Event table is used for other tables too, they relate using column ReferenceId.
This is how the C# code looks like (A tool generates this code)
var query = Context.Set<ClaimEntity>().AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(x => x.Events.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedOn).Select(e => e.Action.Code).FirstOrDefault() == "CREATE_CLAIM");
var total = query.Count();

This is the query it sends to SQL Server
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dc].[Claim] AS [c]
    WHERE 
     (
          SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Code]
          FROM [dc].[Event] AS [e]
          INNER JOIN [dc].[Action] AS [a] ON [e].[ActionId] = [a].[Id]
          WHERE [c].[Id] = [e].[ReferenceId]
          ORDER BY [e].[CreatedOn] DESC
        ) = N'CREATE_CLAIM' 
        AND 
        [c].[DeletedOn] IS NULL

We tried using the SSMS Database Engine Tuning Advisor, it gave this optimization options.

We tried this one, but the time of execution was still 4 seconds
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_Event_19_34099162__K3_K2_K10] ON [dc].[Event]
        (
            [ReferenceId] ASC,
            [ActionId] ASC,
            [CreatedOn] ASC
        )WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]


You should use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and share the execution plan. That query is such a typical EF query though...not efficient.


"A tool generates this code" - do you have control over the generated code (i.e. you can override it or influence in some other way)? 2) the diagram does not show relationship between Claim and Event while code assumes that there is one. Is there a particular reason why there is no FK there? 3) Can you please share execution plan and existing indexes in the db?


Try creating an index on Event(ReferenceId, CreatedOn, ActionId) or  Event(ReferenceId, CreatedOn) INCLUDE(ActionId). In general, you want indexes that first support your WHERE or ON conditions, then the ORDER BY, any column referenced in a MIN() or MAX() aggregate (not applicable here), and then optionally coverage of other referenced columns. Having ActionId before CreatedOn was likely reducing the index's effectiveness.

Here is the execution plan @SeanLange https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJoQWhcl0

@GuruStron 1) yes, I can override the code generated and 2) the code builds the relationship between Claim and Event, but there is no relationship in the database because Event table holds records from different modules. 3) I've shared the execution plan in the previous comment

The estimated execution plan is not really helpful here. Can you post the actual execution plan?

@SeanLange here is the actual execution plan, thanks https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryUFwVoxA

A data structure like that is going to be inefficient since you want to count claims based on a latest event matching a code. Proper indexing will help ensure that the database will be able to process these queries as fast as possible, but there will be limits since it does need to "touch" a lot of values.
This would be a good case to consider de-normalization to introduce a "current" code stored either at the claim level or as a flag on the most recent event. Either solution would involve creating a "health check" to periodically look for and report on any data inconsistencies. This could then be indexed more efficiently. I would also use a numeric enumeration for such a current code rather than strings, lighter on indexing.
For example, if we add a CurrentStatus on the ClaimEntity:
public enum ClaimStatus
{
    None = 0,
    Created,
    //...
}

The act of adding/updating Events on the ClaimEntity can be encapsulated in the entity so that this method is the sole means of creating a new Event is done via something like "ClaimEntity.AddEvent(code, ...)" This method validates the desired event details, creates and adds the Event to the ClaimEntity.Events collection, and updates the current status on the claim. In this way the query to get "Created" events simplifies to:
var query = Context.Set<ClaimEntity>().AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(x => x.CurrentStatus == ClaimStatus.Created);
var total = query.Count();

The health check can be a background process or something run by the database itself to query claims against their latest statuses, looking for any mismatches. If any are found, they can be corrected but should be reported to the development team to track down how they are possibly allowed to get out of sync.
The alternative would be to add something like an "IsCurrent" flag to the Event where the act of adding an event to a claim would set any/all previous IsCurrent flags to False before adding the new row with an IsCurrent set to True. Again, this would need a health check to search for any claims where there is more than one IsCurrent == True set, or no IsCurrent == True set. (Where there are events present) Here the query would simplify to:
var query = Context.Set<ClaimEntity>().AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(x => x.Events.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsCurrent).Code == "CREATE_CLAIM");
var total = query.Count();

This avoids needing to sort the entire events for every claim. Again, the IsCurrent flag would need to be indexed appropriately.
